# How to show thumbnails gallery images in the footer first section?

Tags: media

[image]i have installed node gallery module as well media gallery but media gallery is not working for my drupal version now i am using node gallery but its show like below image [image]

but i want like [image]

[image]

Comment: Go to manage display of the content type and check the display u have provided .

Comment: please check i have added the image of manage display

Comment: is it a gallery media ?? 
Under format Select thumbnail

Comment: its not a media gallery. its a node gallery item and there is no such thing like thumbnail under format

Answer (score -1):

To do that you can use a views block to list all the pictures you want. After that you can use an image style to crop them like you want.

For the theming, feel free to use [Views Theme Suggestion](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3691/drupal-7-how-to-add-a-template-file-to-theme-a-view-inside-your-custom-module) and Views Preprocess(ex : [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53392/how-to-use-template-preprocess-views-view-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-views-tpl-file)) to add features et style images and content wrappers.

I hope it helped you.

Comment: i am new to drupal can you please tell me the steps to achieve the above output

Comment: Sorry, you have to install [Views Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)

_After i recomand you to know what Views Module [is](https://www.drupal.org/node/2287909)_

Now you can create a [View Block](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/views-module-tutorial/create-block-display)

And use [this example](https://www.drupal.org/node/1497058) to achieve your goal.

To finish, a short introduction to [View Theming] (https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-templates/)

i can't explain it better now but if it's not enough fell free to ask :)

Comment: i follow all the steps but one thing its shows the thumbnail with field title and label i only want the thumbnails there how can i remove that that field title. I have added the pic in the question please check

Comment: hide part is done. field tiitle is hide now. Can you please help me out to know how can i open the colorbox popup on click the thumbnail image rather than opening the new page.